# ui-select optgroup filter dropdown in Magento 2 Grid Filter

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.0

I am trying to group the option using optgroup for ui-select component in magento2 grid, but facing some issue.
It is working fine with the [label,value] options not with optgroup.

What i am trying to achieve?

- Need to show the dropdown with optgroup in grid filter
- Below is the optgroup

```html
{
                  "options": [
                    {
                      "value": "5",
                      "is_active": "1",
                      "label": "Default Category",
                      "optgroup": [
                        {
                          "value": "1",
                          "is_active": "1",
                          "label": "first sub category",
                          "optgroup": [
                            {
                              "value": "4",
                              "is_active": "1",
                              "label": "subcategory child one"
                            },
                            {
                              "value": "3",
                              "is_active": "1",
                              "label": "subcategory child two"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "total": 10
                }
```

- On search, need to call ajax and get the result
- Below is the adminhtml ui component code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">

    <filters name="listing_filters">
    <filterSelect
        name="store_id11"
        provider="${ $.parentName }"
        sortOrder="150"
        component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select"
        template="Magento_MediaGalleryUi/grid/filters/elements/ui-select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <!--<item name="entityType" xsi:type="string">cms_page</item>
                    <item name="identityColumn" xsi:type="string">page_id</item>-->
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="searchOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="isDisplayMissingValuePlaceholder" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="isDisplayEmptyPlaceholder" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="isRemoveSelectedIcon" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="filterPlaceholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Asset Title</item>
                    <item name="emptyOptionsHtml" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start typing to find assets</item>
                    <item name="filterRateLimit" xsi:type="string" translate="true">1000</item>
                    <item name="filterRateLimitMethod" xsi:type="string" translate="true">notifyWhenChangesStop</item>
                    <item name="searchUrl" xsi:type="url" path="customwebsitelist/employee/index" />
                    <!--item name="validationUrl" xsi:type="url" path="media_gallery/asset/getSelected"/-->
                    <!--item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item-->
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <!--<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>-->
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>

                <caption translate="true">– Please Select assets –</caption>
                <label translate="true">Asset1</label>
                <dataScope>store_id11</dataScope>
            </settings>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

- Below is the dropdown in sales order grid

[image]

- Below is the issue.

[image]

If we select any child option it is throwing error as "Entity1 with ID: %s doesn't exist".

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Have the same issue. Did you ever find a solution? Thanks

Comment: The issue is related to not properly implemented logic in core. `ui-select` is not designed for using tree and search together, only static tree. If I will have a time I will  check about workaround for (needs to write custom ui-select component)

Comment: Yes, it is working with validationUrl. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Create Custom UI Select Component**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/base/web/js/grid/filters/elements/ui-select.js`

```js
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
    'underscore'
], function (Select, _) {
    'use strict';

    return Select.extend({
        getSelected: function () {
            if (!this.searchOptions) {
                return this._super();
            }

            return this.lookupSelectedOptions(this.cacheOptions.plain, this.value());
        },
        /**
         * @param {*[]} source
         * @param {*[]|String} selected
         * @param {*[]|null} result
         * @param {String|null} separator
         * @returns {*[]}
         */
        lookupSelectedOptions: function (source, selected, result, separator) {
            let i = 0, length;
            separator = separator || this.separator;
            result    = result || [];
            source = _.compact(source);
            length = source.length;

            for (i; i < length; i++) {
                if (_.isArray(selected) ? _.contains(selected, source[i].value) : selected == source[i].value) {
                    result.push(source[i]);
                }

                if (source[i].hasOwnProperty(separator)) {
                    this.lookupSelectedOptions.call(this, source[i][separator], selected, result);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    });
});
```

**2. Use Custom UI Component**

```
<filterSelect component="Acme_StackExchange/js/grid/filters/elements/ui-select"
```

[image]

P.S. Don't forget to implement `<item name="validationUrl" xsi:type="url" path="acme/select/validation"/>` for lookup dynamic options labels on load

Comment: I went with the approach I mentioned above, but this looks like it could also work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. Basically you need to provide the already chosen value as a select option. Here's an example of what I mean

```
<field name="product_1" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="isRemoveSelectedIcon" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="searchOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="searchUrl" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/product/search"/>
                <item name="filterPlaceholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Name or SKU</item>
                <item name="emptyOptionsHtml" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start typing to find products</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">look</item>
                <item name="filterRateLimit" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                <item name="filterRateLimitMethod" xsi:type="string" translate="true">notifyWhenChangesStop</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <required>true</required>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
            <label translate="true">Product 1</label>
            <dataScope>product_1</dataScope>
            <componentType>field</componentType>
            <listens>
                <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
            </listens>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Look\Column\Product1\Options" />
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Where what I added to fix the issue is this section

```
<formElements>
        <select>
            <settings>
                <options class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Look\Column\Product1\Options" />
            </settings>
        </select>
    </formElements>
```

Where this options class is making a query to my custom table and getting the product ID and the product name and creating a single option with those as value => label and returning it. This works perfectly; now when the form loads the product chooser will show the already selected option the same way it does when the option is first selected